# Avoiding multiple subqueries to increase query speed

Tags: mysql

I have one table that lists orders we receive. One row per order.

A second table records transactions associated with the order.

I am trying to produce a report that shows one order per row and on each row to display the total value of the various types of transactions.

My query is:

```
select 
orders.orderID, 
customers.username, 
(select sum(amount) from transactions where transactions.orderID=orders.orderID and transactionType IN (17) ) cost,
(select sum(amount) from transactions where transactions.orderID=orders.orderID and transactionType IN (18,19,20) ) surcharges,
(select sum(amount) from transactions where transactions.orderID=orders.orderID and transactionType IN (21,22) ) payments_received
from orders 
left join customers on orders.customerID=customers.customerID 
order by orderID
```

But this is pretty slow. I have indexes on the appropriate columns.

Can I avoid doing three subqueries and instead just run one query that spits out cost, surcharges and payments_received?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT orders.orderid
     , customers.username
     , Sum(CASE WHEN transactions.transactiontype IN (17        ) THEN transactions.amount END) As cost
     , Sum(CASE WHEN transactions.transactiontype IN (18, 19, 20) THEN transactions.amount END) As surcharges
     , Sum(CASE WHEN transactions.transactiontype IN (21, 22    ) THEN transactions.amount END) As payments_received
FROM   orders
 LEFT
  JOIN customers
    ON customers.customerid = orders.customerid
 LEFT
  JOIN transactions
    ON transactions.orderid = orders.orderid
GROUP
    BY orders.orderid
     , customers.username
ORDER
    BY orders.orderid
```

Comment: Thank you for this approach. I am working through it now.

If we have multiple transactions for the same order that are the same transactionType then I assume your approach won't work?

Comment: It should work. There's no `DISTINCT` in the query, so all the rows will be joined.

Comment: Note that this won't make use of the `transactiontype` index. If it's still slow, you could try adding `WHERE transactions.transactiontype BETWEEN 17 and 22` to the query.

Comment: @Barmar very good point! However I would put that on the `ON` clause, not the WHERE.

Comment: Good point -- I forgot that it's a LEFT JOIN, and WHERE would filter out the rows with no match.